# "enable wireless" option gone after installing rtlwifi_new

Tags: 17.04, realtek-wireless

I have a hp pavillion and it uses the realtek rtl8723be wifi adapter. I had a weak signal so I installed rtlwifi_new and the installation said it was successful. After I rebooted there was no enable wireless option available. Help please! I'm on a fresh install of 17.04 and this is the only change Iv'e tried to make.

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be`?  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8732be': Required key not available

Comment: Sorry I can't paste code as I have no internet access. I'm doing this from my phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `secure boot` in your BIOS.

**Update #1:**

Disabling `secure boot` now gets the driver to load.

**Update #2:**

There are issues with signal strength. This may be due to an incorrect antenna setting for your configuration. Try this...

Reboot. After the system comes up:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Now test. If that still does not work, then try

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Depending on which ant_sel command makes the signal strength better, then edit `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` so:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Add or change the line to:

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

or

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Then reboot and retest.

Comment: Ok that worked! Now I can't get a strong signal. It won't connect at all and I don't have Ethernet. I tried:      echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" but it didn't work

Comment: Is the signal strength the same as before you installed the new driver? Is your router set to WPA2-AES? You didn't use the "options" command correctly. Where did you see to use that?

Comment: It's the same strength as before and it is set to WPA & WPA2 Personal

Comment: Sudo tee etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf was used as well

Comment: I saw that it increased the signal from a similar thread

Comment: I valued try to find it again if you like, but My onlybinternet is on my phone right now

Comment: @MMelvin0581 see my update #2.

Comment: Ok, I'm ran sudo apt-get update and upgrade so it's taking a while bc of the slow connection. I will try that in a second.

Comment: That's just clicking the check right?